# Why the extra \" is needed bash command line but not in script?

Tags: bash

Works in cmd line only:

```
SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd $( dirname \"$0\" ) ; pwd -P )
```

Works in script file only:

```
SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd $( dirname $0 ) ; pwd -P )
```

This is true for both Linux and Mac. Expert please explain?

Comment: You should be using `SCRIPT_DIR="$(cd $(dirname "$0"); pwd -P)"` in both scenarios.  The spacing inside the `$(…)` notation is not a critical change; the use of double quotes around `"$0"` is critical; I'm not certain that the outer double quotes are necessary, but they do no harm either.  What's in `$0` in the two cases?

Comment: @Jonathan the outer quotes aren't needed but you're missing some others that are: `$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd -P)`.

Comment: @TomFenech: Oh, yes, dammit!  The rules got very complicated somewhere along the line — it wasn't as bad back in the bad old days (say the early 1980s).

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you use `$0` on a bash command line the value is

```
$> echo "$0"
-bash
```

If you use it unquoted `dirname $0` it will give this error:

```
dirname: invalid option -- 'b'
```

Due to presence of hyphen at the start.

Note that you can use `--` after `dirname` as well:

```
SCRIPT_DIR=$( cd $( dirname -- $0 ) ; pwd -P )
```

Comment: The [`dirname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html) command has no business taking options!  POSIX doesn't mention any.  It should not emit error messages when given names that start with `-`!  Dammit, it breaks things like this.  (Having said which, I have seen that on some systems it does screw up like this; one of my Macs gets such an error — I simply don't use it enough to have tracked down where it comes from and have fixed it.)  But Mac OS X `dirname` (as provided by Bash, but also `/usr/bin/dirname`) does complain.)

Comment: Actually using `dirname -- $0` from command line doesn't make any sense since it will always produce a DOT as output.

Comment: Don't forget all the required quotes to protect against pathnames with spaces.

Comment: Yes I understand but isn't `$0` always `-bash` from command line

Comment: Quotes don't protect against undefined options anyway; their only job is to prevent the shell from modifying the argument before it is passed to the command.